# Too Many Requests for twitter using openvpn (aws ec2)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, openvpn, elastic-ip

I'm a bit puzzled by a strange situation. I'll add that the configuration of openvpn (using EC2 AWS instances) is rather postural according to official guides.

I tried  to give **different ip** by closing instances and running it. Besides that i have also assigns **elastic IP** to the instance but it doesn't give anything.

I can't get into Twitter. Other sites work very well. Every time i gets *Too Many Requests*  information. What is this and how to get around it ? -my pc home system is ubuntu (without dns leaks)